# ¿Quitar comas de un input js?

Tags: javascript

Cordial Saludo.

Les comento lo que deseo hacer:

Tengo un input que captura un valor: ejemplo: 500,000
Capturo ese input con Js, y quiero quitarle la coma para poder hacer unos calculos.

Como puedo hacerlo?

```js
       var  TotalDevengado = $("#TotalDevengado").val();
          inicio = ",",
          subCadena = TotalDevengado.substring(inicio);
          alert(subCadena)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="TotalDevengado" value="500,000"/>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Eso he intentado, pero no se como se hace

Comment: porque no declaras tu input type number. si tienes problemas haces el parser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes intentar usando el `replace()` así:

```js
var TotalDevengado = "500,000,000,000";
TotalDevengado = TotalDevengado.replace(/,/g, "");
alert(TotalDevengado)
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funcionó

Comment: Perfecto, que bueno que te funcionara, me puedes tildar mi pregunta como valida? gracias

Comment: ***Funciona si tienes cifras con una sola coma***. Si el total devengado fuera 5,000,000 el resultado será: 5000,000. Saludos.

Comment: Si, ya me acabé de dar cuenta haciendo pruebas

Comment: Entonces si tiene un monto de 15,75 lo tomará como **1575** ¿realmente eso es afectivo para hacer cálculos? la misma historia con la respuesta de @Orici

Comment: Listo @AndresRodriguez edite mi respuesta prueba y me avisas

Comment: Gracias, eso era lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas no es quitar comas, lo que debes hacer es un conversión explicita al monto que tengas en **TotalDevengado** porque si tuvieses montos con valores decimales como por ejemplo 15,55 quitar las comas lo único que haría es devolverte 1555 un monto totalmente diferente al esperado, para ello puedes emplear **parseFloat()**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="TotalDevengado">
    <button onclick=calcular()>calcular</button >
</body>
<script>
  function calcular() {
    var  TotalDevengado = $("#TotalDevengado").val();
    var totalDevengadoFloat = parseFloat(TotalDevengado);
    console.log(totalDevengadoFloat);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Tambien necesito tener los otros valores, si pongo "80,000,000", me devuelve "80", tambien necesito los otros numeros...

Comment: Ah ok, es por el tipo de cultura que tiene tu monto, lo normal seria que uses puntos en lugar de comas, déjame ver que encuentro

Answer (score 0):

En javascript existe la función **replace** para cambiar una parte de un string, en este caso el carácter ',' por ninguno ''. El problema es que en principio solo cambia la primera aparición. Hay que hacer que itere hasta "limpiar" todo el string.

#### Código solución

```
function cleanChar(str, char) {
    console.log('cleanChar()'); // HACK: trace
    while (true) {
        var result_1 = str.replace(char, '');
        if (result_1 === str) {
            break;
        }
        str = result_1;
    }
    return str;
}
var str = '100,000,000';
var result = cleanChar(str, ',');
console.log('Origin: ' + str + ' | Result: ' + result);
```

#### Resultado

```
cleanChar()
VM124:14 Origin: 100,000,000 | Result: 100000000
```

Comment: puede usar la funcion replace con una expresion regular , y evitas el  while

Answer (score 0):

Este código es el que me funciona:

```
String.prototype.toNum = function () {
    return parseFloat(this.split(' ').join('').split(',').join('') || 0);
}
```

Puedes incluso hacer una alternativa a enteros:

```
String.prototype.toInt = function () {
    return parseInt(this.split(' ').join('').split(',').join('') || 0);
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace es que elimina los espacios en blanco y las comas, y posteriormente lo "parsea" a número. La manera de utilizarla es así:

```js
String.prototype.toInt = function (){    
    return parseInt(this.split(' ').join('').split(',').join('') || 0);
}

// Incluso pensándolo como algo más genérico:

toInt = function(val){
  var result;
  if (typeof val === "string")
    result = parseInt(val.split(' ').join('').split(',').join('') || 0);
  else if (typeof val === "number")
    result = parseInt(val);
  else if (typeof val === "object")
    result = 0;
  return result;
}

var TotalDevengado = "500,000".toInt();
var TotalDevengado2 = toInt("500,000");
console.log({TotalDevengado, TotalDevengado2});
```

Comment: No se como hacerlo funcionar...

Answer (score 0):

```
  function quita_comas(numero){
    var cadenas = numero.split(",");
    cadena_sin_comas = "";
    for(i = 0; i < cadenas.length;i++){
      cadena_sin_comas = cadena_sin_comas+cadenas[i];
    }
    return cadena_sin_comas;
  }
```

Comment: Las respuestas de puro código no educan ni enseñan. Agrega comentarios para que cualquiera pueda entender tu solución.